# リストアイテム全体に適用されるセレクターの実現方法

Tags: android

```xml
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

  <!-- これはネットワーク経由で読み込む画像 -->
  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/image"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      tools:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/text"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
      android:layout_margin="8dp"
      tools:text="hogehoge"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

上記のようなレイアウトをRecyclerViewのアイテムのレイアウトとして設定しています。
これにセレクターを適用すると、当然ですがレイアウトの背景のみ変化するため、ImageViewの見た目はそのままになります。

ImageViewも背景と同様のセレクターの効果（全体に半透明の黒がブレンドされるようなイメージ）を適用したいと考えています。

背景はセレクター、画像はColorFilterをそれぞれ使うことでも実現は出来るのですが、

- レイアウトが複雑になると対応が難しい（このレイアウトの中に背景色を持つViewが入った場合や、ImageViewが増えた場合など）
- 定義場所がxml, コードに分散され保守しづらい

等の問題が有ります。

レイアウト全体に適用可能なフィルターのような機能はどのように実現するのがよいのでしょうか？

※ 前提条件として対象OSは4.0-5.0で、Material Designは今回導入しません。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fkm さんの別解になりますが、`FrameLayout` の `foreground` を使う方法はいかがでしょうか。

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:foreground="@drawable/foreground_selector"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        ...
```

また、`ListView` で良ければ、`android:drawSelectorOnTop` 属性を指定する手もあります。
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:drawSelectorOnTop

Comment: うまくいきました。FrameLayoutにforegroundなんていう便利な属性があったとは知りませんでした！

Answer (score 1):

的外れかもしれませんが、ルートとなるレイアウトをFrameLayoutやRelativeLayoutにして、全体を覆うViewを上に重ねてしまうのはどうでしょうか？

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
     中略
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/xxxx"/>
</FrameLayout>
```